# The short survey bar is still visible

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Yesterday I took the short satisfaction survey. When I finished it, the blue bar on top of the browser was still visible and I thought it was a cache issue.

Today I logged in with my *only* SO account but it's still there.

[image]

The browser is Mozilla Quantum 68.0.1 running on Ubuntu 19.04.

Is this normal? Shouldn't it go away?

Comment: @DavyM Yes I have, I keep clicking the X to close and it does close. Then I, for instance, go answer a question and that page has the bar and I have to click X again. In fact, when I return to the first page it reappears.

Comment: This is a bug. Looking into it. Once you either take the survey or dismiss the notice, it should stay gone, at least for a few months (at which point you might be randomly selected again)

Comment: @YaakovEllis this bug probably increases the number of participants

Comment: Marking this as completed for the time being, as we think that we have addressed the issue. If anyone still sees it, ping here please.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Like I said in my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388474/the-short-survey-bar-is-still-visible/388485#comment721704_388485), it's gone and never returned. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We just pushed a change to production that should fix the issue. Please let me know if the banner keeps showing up.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Its not on the main page https://stackoverflow.com/, but as soon as I click a question or have a look at a profile, it pops up again. If one clicks the survey it states `You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired.` Checked it 2 seconds ago

Comment: It's not corrected (I'm assuming it's a bug). If I close it on the main page then reload the page it shows up again. So, no, it's not fixed.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Sorry about that, I’ll keep digging.

Comment: @RuiBarradas maybe check the developer console of the browser if you have any errors there. That might help the dev team localizing the issue. Knowing there are no errors is as useful as having errors (in which case the exact error and location is helpful I guess). Unless Adam Lear already has tons of logging from your browser ....

Comment: @RuiBarradas Do you have a cookie called either `ssb` or `notice-ssb`? If so, can you share its contents, please?

Comment: @Adam Do you have a cookie called either `ssb` or `notice-ssb`? If so, can you share its contents, please?

Comment: @AdamLear I do not have such a cookie. Here are all cookies from SO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMvL2.png

Comment: And a screenshot of the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFqtQ.png

Comment: @Adam Thanks, much appreciated. Can you think of anything on your end that would prevent the cookie from being set? Browser extensions, etc.

Comment: I have AdBlocker, but I disabled it on the start of the survey (there was a note that one should disable it) and I also have `I don't care about cookies` extension. I disabled both again, and dismissed the survey and refreshed,  but still no `ssb` cookie.

Comment: @Adam Aha, but now on the backend I'm seeing the survey as dismissed. If you re-enable the extensions, does the survey banner come back?

Comment: The survey banner comes back, no matter if I enable my 2 extensions or not.

Comment: Same on chrome, where I have no extensions.

Comment: @Adam Hmm, well there goes that theory. But now I don't have a better lead since as far as I can tell, we recorded your dismissal. I'll have to keep digging.

Comment: Gone. Suddenly it was gone and I didn't remove any cookies or anything. Everything seems to be normal.

Comment: What triggers this? I'd like to take the survey, too.

Comment: @JL2210 I don’t have the exact mechanics of this in front of me right now, but basically.... it’s random. We invite a percentage of visitors (both logged in and anonymous), so you might get a prompt at some point.

Comment: I have been getting the survey banner for the past few days.  If I click on it I get directed to the main SO page (apparently the survey page no longer exists)

Comment: @Jason The survey should exist if you have been invited... I suspect a bug. Investigating.

Comment: the link is https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect

Comment: @Jason Thanks. I put a proposed fix in a PR, but need to get it tested/reviewed... Should be able to deploy the fix tomorrow, I think. Sorry about that.

Comment: This seems to be recurring for me now. I keep getting asked even though I've already filled it out.

Comment: @BenBolker Are you able to dismiss the banner or does it persist? Are you blocking or auto-clearing any cookies? In particular, the one I'm interested here is called `ssb`.

Comment: it keeps coming back.  I'm not blocking or auto-clearing cookies, to my knowledge.  It looks like I have 12 cookies from StackOverflow, not sure how to examine them individually (Firefox 69.0.1 on MacOS 10.11.6) ...

Comment: @BenBolker I don't have a Mac handy, but assuming it's similar to Windows... cookies should be under the Storage tab in the dev tools.

Comment: no `ssb`.  When I look at the Storage tab I see that I have: __gads, __qca, _gat, _ga, _gid, acct, cc, notice-ctt, prov, sgt, superSeecretTrackingCookie2, and one with a blank name.  When I click through to the survey it tells me I already took it.